# Reading N number of files using thread concept in java

Tags: multithreading

How to read N number of lines from a file using thread concept.

Suppose a file contains N number of lines, Contents will be added dynamically.

I need to read the line which contains the word "ERROR","Shutdown","Recovery","failed".

Here I need to use the thread concept because, First time my file reads 1-100 lines and it is checking for the word,if there a particular word (Error, Shutdown, Recovery, failed) it should store it in a string.

Next time my thread is starts to read after 2 minutes then it should start reading from the 101-200 lines, it should not read again from the first line of the file.

It should keep on continuously read the file after every 2 minutes. Please provide me related coding for the one I have requested.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service. Also, add what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about what a thread is. It has nothing to do with file read offsets. What you need is a `java.io.RandomAccessFile`. The first time you read until EOF and store the count of bytes read. Each next time to call `skipBytes()` before start reading. And so on...